# Read unknown amount of int from file to linked list

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, linked-list, realloc

I am trying to read an unknown number of integers from a file and store them in a int pointer in a linked list:

```
typedef struct BCP BCP;

struct BCP
{
    int *schedule;
    BCP *next;
};
```

Then, assuming `nouveauBCP` is a node:

```
nouveauBCP->schedule = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); 
fscanf(P,"%d", &nouveauBCP->schedule); 
printf("%d |",nouveauBCP->schedule);

while (fgetc (P) != '\n') 
{
    nouveauBCP->schedule = (int*)realloc(nouveauBCP->schedule, sizeof(int));
    fscanf(P,"%d", nouveauBCP->schedule[i]);
    printf("%d-", nouveauBCP->schedule[i]);
    i++;
}
```

How can i access to read and write in `nouveauBCP->schedule[i]? Is it even possible to use realloc inside of a linked list?

Comment: Tip: Your code doesn't use `next`, so it stands to reason that you are misunderstanding what a "linked list" is. Please continue studying your algorithms and datastructures books.

Comment: You certainly can `realloc` (the fact that it is used in a linked list is irrelevant). But of course it doesn't make sense to `realloc` each time with the same size as you are doing - the size needs to be increased. There are other major problems with your code but it's not productive to comment on them unless you show complete code.

Comment: You need to decide if you are trying to use a linked list or an array.  A linked list gives you the freedom to allocate per a node but that is clearly not what your doing here.

Comment: Linked list is when each node holds a single int value and the next pointer points to the next element in the list. That is to say, in each iteration you would allocate space for a new node and in that node set the schedule (which should be an int, not a pointer to an int). The first node you create becomes the head of the list, so store that in a variable. And then you need the current tail of the list to be able to add a new element to the end of the list in the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others pointed your code is not taking advantage of linked list and thus it is a bit odd looking, but since I do not know the overall design you have, I will concentrate on the piece of code you submitted.

You are missing initialization of variable `i` and your realloc() does not increase the amount of memory pointed by `schedule` field.
I took the code you provided and added few corrections:

```
nouveauBCP->schedule = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); 
fscanf(P,"%d", &nouveauBCP->schedule); 
printf("%d |",nouveauBCP->schedule);
int i = 0; //initialize i variable
while (fgetc (P) != '\n') 
{
    if(i>1) // we do not want to reallocate if i is less than 1
    {
        nouveauBCP->schedule = (int*)realloc(nouveauBCP->schedule, i*sizeof(int));
    }
    fscanf(P,"%d", &nouveauBCP->schedule[i]); //fscanf needs a pointer to memory
    printf("%d-", nouveauBCP->schedule[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Please note that [fscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/?kw=fscanf) needs a pointer to the memory where the integer will be stored and thus you should use `&nouveauBCP->schedule[i]`.

Comment: Lots of bugs! For example `&nouveauBCP->schedule` which should be `nouveauBCP->schedule` which is for clarity better written as `&nouveauBCP->schedule[0]`. And then, where is the character going to that is read with `fgetc`? And what if `realloc` fails? And shouldn't the `realloc` be with `(i+1)*sizeof(int)`?

Comment: the code i gave isn't complete, what i was missing is `&nouveauBCP->schedule[0]` and i thought the argument of `realloc ` was the size of the new block, anyway thanks so much, iappreciate the help :)